# How to Get the NodeRef of the Opened Document in Alfresco Share

Tags: yui, alfresco, alfresco-share

I am planning to generate direct download link from the client side when user open a document in document details window.
In order to do that I want to access noderef of the opened document. Can someone mention how to access noderef of the opened document from alfresco share client side (javascript).

Comment: What do you mean by the "opened document"? The document details page? A document you downloaded some time ago? Something else?

Comment: Yes I mean the document details page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Good for you that I've done that in the past for a customer.

You'll need to change the following files (create a module or just override them)

- document-links.get.properties (add a new label for download)
- document-links.get.head.ftl (include your new overridded client side JavaScript)
- document-links.get.html.ftl (add a new field like the current page url)

  ```
      <h3 class="thin dark">${msg("page.download")}</h3>
      <div class="link-info">
         <input id="${el}-download" value="${document.node.contentURL}"/>
         <a href="#" name=".onCopyLinkClick" class="${el} hidden">${msg("page.copy")}</a>
      </div>
  ```
- document-links.js (client side JavaScript)

> onReady: function DocumentLinks_onReady() {
>        // Display copy links
>        if (this.hasClipboard) {
>            Dom.removeClass(Selector.query("a.hidden", this.id), "hidden");
>        }
>
> ```
>  // Make sure text fields auto select the text on focus
>  Event.addListener(Selector.query("input", this.id), "focus", this._handleFocus);
>
>  // Prefix some of the urls with values from the client
>  Dom.get(this.id + "-page").value = document.location.href;
>
>  // added Download link
>  var contentURL = Dom.get(this.id + "-download").value;
>  Dom.get(this.id + "-download").value = window.location.protocol + "//" + window.location.host + "/alfresco/d/a" +
> ```
>
> contentURL.replace('api/node/content/', '');  }